# Pass by reference with template functions C++

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-reference

I'm Trying to make a template function and pass two variables to it by reference , every thing sounds good but it never compiled and the error message is :-

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I tried a small part of code and it gives me same error, any help please??

And this a part of code, the all other code is just like this:

```
int size , found = -1 ; 

template<class type> Read_Data( type &key , type &arr)
{ 
    cout << " please enter the size of your set \n " ; 
    cin >> size ;
    arr = new type[size]; 

    cout << " please enter the elements of your set : \n " ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i <size ; i ++ )
    {
        cout << " enter element number " << i << ": "  ;  
        cin >> arr[i] ;
    }
    cout << " please enter the key elemente you want to search for : \n " ;
    cin >> key ; 
}

void main(void)
{ 
    int key , arr ; 
    Read_Data (key, arr);

    /*after these function there is two other functions one to search for key 
    in array "arr" and other to print the key on the screen */ 
}
```

Comment: `Read_Data` has no return type and `void main(void)` is non-standard.

Comment: So what makes you think it is related to templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing a couple of things to get the code compiling (resolving the error you saw).

Basically, in `int main()`, you need to specify the type when instantiating the template, as in:

```
Read_Data <int> (key, value);
```

so that the compiler knows what type you really want to instantiate it with.

Also note that the array should be of type `int *`. So in the templated function the signature has to change to:

```
template<class type> Read_Data( type &key , type* &arr)
```

This is the corrected code which won't show the error you were previously seeing:

```
#include<iostream>  

using namespace std;

int size , found = -1 ; 

template<class type> void Read_Data( type &key , type* &arr)
{ 
    cout << " please enter the size of your set \n " ; 
    cin >> size ;
    arr = new type[size]; 
    cout << " please enter the elements of your set : \n " ;

    for (int i = 0 ; i <size ; i ++ )
    {   
        cout << " enter element number " << i << ": "  ;   
        cin >> arr[i] ;
    }   

    cout << " please enter the key elemente you want to search for : \n " ;
    cin >> key;                                                                                                                                         
}

int main()
{   
    int key;
    int * arr;
    Read_Data<int> (key, arr);

    /* after these function there is two other functions one to search for key 
     * in array "arr" and other to print the key on the screen 
     */ 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a return-value type in the declaration of function `Read_Data`.

A few examples:

```
template<class type> void Read_Data( type &key , type &arr)
template<class type> int  Read_Data( type &key , type &arr)
template<class type> type Read_Data( type &key , type &arr)
```

The first example is probably what you need if you're not planning to return anything in that function...

BTW, you also need to:

- In function `main`, change `int arr` to `int* arr`.
- In function `main`, change `Read_Data` to `Read_Data<int>`.
- In function `main`, call `delete[] arr` after you finish using it.
- In function `Read_Data`, change `type &arr` to `type* &arr`.

Comment: No need to explicitly specify the type in the call to `Read_Data`. Type deduction will take care of that.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious: Thanks for the info; wasn't aware of that (actually, I thought the default return-value type was `int`). In any case, I think it is better to explicitly declare the return-value type, even for the sake of code-readability.

Comment: What are you talking about? The type parameter is not being used to specify the return type.

Comment: I tried the fist example and I added the delete[] arr; to the end of Read_data() function , and I don't really know what this command do , take in consideration I will use "arr" in other parts of code

Comment: @Captain Obvlious: I didn't say that. I said that when there's no return-value type, as far as I know, the compiler assumes `int`.

Comment: @ user3425180: you should call `delete[] arr` in `main`, unless you're not planning to use it there. But from the rest of your code, it appears that you do have some plans to use it after calling `Read_Data` (otherwise, you might as well declare it locally in that function, instead of passing it as an argument).

Comment: @barakmanos : yes I'm planning to use it in other parts , but this is an assignment , the instructor need from us to make the main function handle these other functions of 'Read_Data' and 'Processing' and 'Out_Data' , thanks very much it works now

Comment: @user3425180: You just need to make sure that you `delete[] arr` when you finish using it. It doesn't have to be in function `main`, but from the structure of your code, it appears to be the correct place to call it from.

Comment: @barakmanos : excuse me , I don't really know what this line of code do  `delete[] arr`

Comment: @user3425180: You can look at `delete[] arr` as the opposite of `arr = new[...]`. Every dynamic memory allocation must be preceded with a corresponding memory de-allocation at some later point in the execution of your program. Otherwise, you end up with memory leaks.